Find the smallest integer, $k>3$, such that the angle is on the y-axis
You have an angle $(5π)/6$ multiplied by $k$. So $(5π*k)/6.$  Find the smallest integer for $k$ that is greater than $3$ such that the angle is either $π/2$ or $(3π)/2$. Find the integer value of $k$.
I did $(5π*k)/6 = π/2 + π n $
and I got $(5k-3)/6 = n $
and from there I guess I could keep trying values for $k $ until I get an integer
but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Hint: $5(3+6t)-6(2+5t)=3$

sorry I am unable to get it with the hint

How about $$\frac{5(3+6t)}6=\frac36+(2+5t)$$

For $6$ to divide $5k-3$, you need $k$ to be an odd multiple of $3$

@MathLearner:  did you read the question carefully?  It seems to me that OP put in significant effort and even indicated how to solve the problem by brute force and was merely asking for a better way

@J.W.Tanner You are right.

You have transformed this to a divisibility problem.
$6$ divides $5k-3\iff2$ and $3$ divide $5k-3$.
$2$ divides $5k-3\iff k$ is odd, and $3$ divides $5k-3\iff 3$ divides $k$.
Can you take it from here?
